# UNIX sort unique guaranteed to give first

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

I like to use the `-u` option of the UNIX `sort` utility to get unique lines based on a particular subset of columns, e.g.  `sort -u  -k1,1  -k4,4`

I have looked extensively in UNIX `sort` and GNU `sort` documentation, and I cannot find any **guarantee** that the `-u` option will return the *first* instance (like the `uniq` utility) **after** sorting by the specified keys.

It seems to work as desired in practice (sort by keys, then give first instance of each unique key combination), but I was hoping for some kind of guarantee in the documentation to put my paranoia at ease.

Does anyone know of such a guarantee?

Comment: Why not just use `uniq` if it works as you'd like/feel confident in, _e.g._ `uniq ... | sort | ...`?

Comment: Good point, but `uniq` only operates on entire lines.  But you can use `sort -u` on  subset of columns.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps something like `cut -f 1,4 | uniq | sort | ...`, _i.e._ using `cut` to get the columns in which you're interested?

Answer (score 1):

I think the code for such a small utility is likely the only place you'll find such a guarantee. You can enable more debugging output as well if you'd like to see how it is working.

If you look through the code for GNU `sort`, it appears that the uniqueness testing happens after all sorting is completed, when it is iterating through the sorted contents of the temporary files created by the sorting process.

This happens in a [while loop](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/sort.c#2969) that compares the previous line `savedline` with `smallest`, which is the next smallest input line which would be output.

Thus, my opinion would be that it will process your sorting criteria first, then unique the output at the last step.

Comment: it's true.  But if it is not guaranteed in the man page or somewhere, then it is technically possible that in some future "update" of `sort`, the code may be changed and it no longer be true.

Comment: Then I think your answer is that there is no guarantee and this is an implementation detail.